# How to fix openssl_private_decrypt() error in PHP?

Tags: php, openssl

I need finish this part of school project.

**Create openssl public and private key**

```
function openssl($text){
    # privaten Schlüssel erzeugen
    $res=openssl_pkey_new();
    # privaten Schlüssel zu String
    openssl_pkey_export($res, $privatekey);
    # öffentlichen Schlüssel
    $publickey=openssl_pkey_get_details($res);
    $publickey=$publickey["key"];
    openssl_public_encrypt($text, $crypttext, $publickey);
    $filenameCrypttext = "crypttext.txt";
    $filenamePrivatekeyText = "privatekey.txt";
    $files = [$filenameCrypttext, $filenamePrivatekeyText];
    createFile($crypttext, $filenameCrypttext);
    createFile($privatekey,$filenamePrivatekeyText);
    downloadZip($files);
}
function createFile($crypttext, $filename){
    file_put_contents($filename, $crypttext.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}

function downloadZip($files){
    $zipname = "packet.zip";
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
    foreach ($files as $file){
        $zip->addFile($file);
    }
    $zip->close();
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        unlink($file);
    }

    header("Location: download.php?filename=$zipname");
}
```

I download my 2 files *crypttext.txt* and *privatekey.txt* as zip. Later I want to upload them.

[**Encrypted**](https://pastebin.com/LAvGLdFf)

[**Privatekey**](https://pastebin.com/0awFyxQx)

**And the following code is my decryption function**

```
<div class="container">
<br>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <label>Encrypted Text</label>
    <textarea name="encrypted_text"  placeholder="Text einfügen" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
    <label>Private Key </label>
    <textarea name="private_key"  placeholder="Text einfügen" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Hochladen</button>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['encrypted_text'], $_POST['private_key'])){
    echo 'isset';
    $encrypted = $_POST['encrypted_text'];
    $privatekey = $_POST['private_key'];
    $res = openssl_get_privatekey($privatekey);
    openssl_private_decrypt($encrypted, $decrypted, $res);
    echo '<br>';
    echo $decrypted;
    echo '<br>';
}
?>
```

I dont get a result.
Where is my misstake?

Comment: First of all you have two different variables: $privatekey and $privatekey_text and the second one is undefined. Secondly (considering the variables' names are ok) you assign to $privatekey value from 'decrypted_text'. Shouldn't you use 'private_key'?

Comment: Okay, I changed the variable name to $privatekey.

Comment: In errorlogs are no errors but now I dont get a result in my echo?

Comment: @PatiK Yes, you are right with 'decrypted_text'. I changed it also to the name encrypted_text. - changed it live in this post.

Comment: If it still doesn't work, perhaps your data is wrong. First of all, are you using the correct key? I see German language - perhaps you have a problem with encoding?

Comment: You can also check if decryption works in the same function that you are encrypting it. If it does, you should go step by step and check, when the error (empty decryption) occurs e.g. whether without zipping it works etc.